# Process every item in a Cosmos DB using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am hoping this is an appropriate usecase for Azure Data Factory.

I have a Cosmos DB that has ~200k records, and I would like to iterate over the entire database, passing each record into a Logic App.  Is there an easy way to foreach over every record?  I thought that Azure Data Factory would have this capability, but the "Lookup + Foreach" combo doesn't like the number of records I have.  My attempts at creating a while loop with the "Lookup + Foreach" pipeline also feels slightly clunky.

I don't feel that 200k records is a large dataset. Am I missing something? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ideal way is for you to use [Change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) mechanism.  This would be a perfect use-case for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions

Comment: Change feed mechanism would work great if there's a change in the container (like data being created or updated). In this case, the data is already there. How do you think it would work?

Comment: I'm curious about this too.  I know I can spin up a VM and push all the row into a Service Bus, then trigger a Logic App to process the Service Bus queue, but I want to try and stick as PaaS as possible.  The loading of the existing data is the hard part that I'm trying to figure out.